# How to use cy.fixture to read multiple records from a json file

Tags: javascript, json, automated-tests, cypress

I made the code below using cy.fixture () to read the records from a Json file.

```
/// <reference types = "cypress" />
describe('Fixtures', () => {

before(() => {
    cy.viewport(1400, 800)
    cy.visit('https://www.adroll.com/')
})

it('Formulário de Cadastro', function() {

    cy.get(':nth-child(8) > .cta > span').click()

    cy.fixture('AdRoll').as('cadastro').then(() => {

        cy.get('#first_name').type(this.cadastro.FirstName)
        cy.get('#last_name').type(this.cadastro.LastName)
        cy.get('#email').type(this.cadastro.CompanyEmail)
        cy.get('#company_phone').type(this.cadastro.ComPhoNum)
        cy.get('#url').type(this.cadastro.CompWebSiteUrl) 
    })

})
```

})

Contents of the Json file with the records to be read by the cy.fixture () command.

```
[
{
    "FirstName": "Leandro",
    "LastName": "Pereira",
    "CompanyEmail": "leandro.nares@gmail.com",
    "ComPhoNum": "991549450",
    "CompWebSiteUrl": "www.kyz.com.br"
},
{
    "FirstName": "Paulo",
    "LastName": "Nares",
    "CompanyEmail": "Paulo.nares@gmail.com",
    "ComPhoNum": "000000000",
    "CompWebSiteUrl": "www.paulo.com.br"
}
]
```

Cypress displays the error message in the image below. I believe the error occurs because I am reading multiple records from the Json file and my code cannot read an array. Can anyone help me adapt the code to read all the records in the Json file?

[image]

Comment: If you have an array, then you'll need to index the elements of the array. So, assuming the JSON file is valid according to Cypress, you should access your data with `this.cadastro[0].FirstName`, etc.

Comment: Thank you, natn2323.
Your suggestion worked, partially, but in fact my idea is that the script will loop, and read each record and make several entries automatically. Same as DataDriven in Selenium.

Comment: Sure, then at this point you just need to iterate over the length of the array.

Comment: natn2323, that's the problem, I don't know how to loop. Can you help make one?

Comment: You could do a basic for-loop in JavaScript. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp). Give it a shot. If you don't figure it out, you can probably find other questions pertaining to different kinds of loops in JavaScript on StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is ; include your fixtures in the testfile like

const adRoll = require('../../fixture/TTT')

```
                   adRoll.forEach(function(input)
                {
                     const Firstname=input.Firstname
                     const Lastname=input.lastname
                    cy.get('#fname').type(Firstname)
                    cy.get('#lname').type(lasttname)
                    


                })
```

Comment: Thankyou ! Works for me perfectly in single fixture JSON with multiple data and not stub API

before describe('Test Single Input Field Form', function() declare :

`const testData = require("../../fixtures/multipleInputFields.json")`

and then

`testData.forEach((data) => {  
const message = data.message 
it('Test Case', function(){      
cy.log("data is:" + data) 
cy.get('#user-message').type(message).should('have.value', message) 
cy.get('#get-input > button').click()  
cy.wait(200) 
cy.get('span#display').should('have.text', message)      
}) 
});`